# JavaScript: eliminate number with decimal .0

Tags: javascript, string, integer, numbers, conditional-statements

I need your advice (I'm a beginner in JS).This is my code:

```js
function fn(pin) {

  if (pin.length === 4 && !isNaN(pin) && pin % parseInt(pin) === 0 && Number(pin) > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false
}

console.log(fn("123a.78")) // false
```

So i check the length, that it is a number, that it is integer and that it is bigger than 0.
But how should i write the condition to eliminate strings of this type: "12.0" (because it also has length of 4 and is also integer)? If i try conditions with pin.parseFloat or parseInt, it will affect strings like this type "1234" as well. Or maybe i write them in the wrong way...

Comment: Go with a regular expression, like `return /^\d{4}$/.test(pin);`. There's really no maths involved.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! It looks like regular expressions can help in many situations in JS. I did not study them yet )). Will go study now )

Comment: Are you just looking for a four digit integer number after parsing the string? Or should `0123` be valid?

Comment: 0123 will also be good. I only want to eliminate numbers with decimal equal to 0 (like 16.0)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a regular expression to validate the input.
The regular expression to validate 4 digits only would look like this: /^[0-9]{4}$/

Regular expressions have methods that allow them to test if variables are of their type.
For instance:

```
const pin = '1234';
const pin2 = '12.4'
const regExp = /^[0-9]{4}$/

regExp.test(pin) //returns true
```

whereas:

`regExp.test(pin2) //returns false`

You can use this validation as the condition in your if/else conditions to execute the code you need.

freecode tutorial on Regular Expressions
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/#es6

Regular expressions playground:
https://regex101.com/